# ¿Cómo puedo ordenar las fechas en un ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist, ordenar, metodos

Estoy intentando hacer un método donde me ordena la lista por fecha en la clase `Temperatures` en el método `ordenarPorData`, pero me aparece el error en `Collections.sort()`. Alguien me puede explicar por qué motivo me da error y por qué no puedo ordenar las fechas de una lista. Muchas gracias.

```
public class Temperatura {

    private LocalDate dia;
    private double maxima;
    private double minima;

    public Temperatura(LocalDate dia, double maxima, double minima) {
        this.dia = dia;
        if (minima < maxima) {
            this.maxima = maxima;
            this.minima = minima;
        } else {
            this.maxima = minima;
            this.minima = maxima;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 3;
        hash = 43 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.dia);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        final Temperatura other = (Temperatura) obj;
        return Objects.equals(this.dia, other.dia);
    }

    public int getAny() {
        return  dia.getYear();
    }
    
    public Month getMes(){
        return dia.getMonth();
    }
    
    public int getMesValor(){
        return dia.getMonthValue();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%10s >> mínima %6.2f màxima %6.2f", 
                CONST.DTF.format(dia), minima, maxima);
    }
}
```

```
public class Temperatures {

    private List<Temperatura> temperatures;

    public Temperatures() {
        temperatures = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public Temperatures(List<Temperatura> temperatures) {
        this.temperatures = temperatures;
    }

    public void afegeix(Temperatura temperatura) throws Maex {
        if (temperatures.isEmpty()) {
            temperatures.add(temperatura);
            return;
        }
        int any = temperatures.get(0).getAny();
        if (temperatura.getAny() != any) {
            throw new Maex("l'any ha de ser " + any);
        }
        int index = temperatures.indexOf(temperatura);
        if (index == -1) {
            temperatures.add(temperatura);
        } else {
            temperatures.set(index, temperatura);
        }
    }

    
    public String llistaPerDates() {
        String llistat = """
                         Llistat ordenat per dates
                         ---------------------------------
                         """;
        ordenarPorData();
            for (Temperatura temperatura : temperatures) {
                llistat += temperatura + "\n";
            }
        return llistat;
    }

    private void ordenarPorData() {
        Collections.sort(temperatures); // Me da error
    }

}
```

```
public class RangDies {

    private LocalDate diaInicial;
    private LocalDate diaFinal;

    public RangDies(LocalDate diaInicial, LocalDate diaFinal) {
        if (diaInicial.compareTo(diaFinal) > 0) {
            LocalDate tmp = diaFinal;
            diaFinal = diaInicial;
            diaInicial = tmp;
        }

        this.diaInicial = diaInicial;
        this.diaFinal = diaFinal;
    }

    public boolean estaDins(LocalDate dia) {
        return dia.compareTo(diaInicial) >= 0
                && dia.compareTo(diaFinal) <= 0;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "des de " + diaInicial + " fins a " + diaFinal;
    }

}
```

Comment: En el código que muestras no hay Collections.sort(), revisar [ask], saludos.

Comment: @Jorgesys. si haces scroll en la clase **Temperatures** encontrarás el **Collections.sort()** :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Con ArrayList de clases propias, el Collections.sort no funciona, tienes que implementar la interfaz Comparable en aquella clase que este en el ArrayList que deseas ordenar y sobrescribir el método @comparteTo, de esta manera se te irá el error y podrás utilizar el Collections.sort sobre ArrayList de clases propias, te dejo un ejemplo:

```
public class Alumno implements Comparable<Alumno>{
//Aributos propios de la clase
private String nombre;
private float notaMedia;

//Constructores
public Alumno(String nombre, float notaMedia) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.notaMedia = notaMedia;
}

//Getters y Setters
public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}   
public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}

public float getNotaMedia() {
    return notaMedia;
}
public void setNotaMedia(float notaMedia) {
    this.notaMedia = notaMedia;
}

//toString
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Alumno: "+this.nombre+", Nota Media: "+this.notaMedia;
}

//compareTo
@Override
/**
 * Ver documentación
 * @see https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Comparable.html
 */
public int compareTo(Alumno o) {
    int res = 0; //La documentación nos dice que en caso de que es igual el método debe retornar 0;
                 // Yo lo cojo como caso base;        
    if(this.notaMedia > o.notaMedia){
        res = 1;   // Si el objeto que llama la función es mayor que el objeto pasado por parámetro
                   // el método debe devolver un número entero positivo (por ejemplo 1)
    }else{
        if(this.notaMedia < o.notaMedia){
            res = -1; // Y por último, si el objeto que llama la función es menor que el objeto pasado por parámetro
                      // el método debe devolver un número entero positivo (por ejemplo -1)
        }
    }        
    return res;
}
```

}

Como funciona es simple:
el Collections.sort() se viene a este método y compara por el atributo que te interese a ti, en el ejemplo se utiliza en base a la nota media.

En tu caso deberías de implementar esta interfaz y sobrescribir el método en tu clase Temperatura, puesto que el ArrayList es de la clase Temperatura.

Answer (score 0):

Para que **Collections.sort();** funcione con **temperatures**, debes crear una clase que podríamos llamar **TemperaturasPorFecha** que implemente la interfaz **Comparator**, y debe tener un método **compare()**.

Quedaría algo así:

```
public class TemperaturasPorFecha implements Comparator<Temperatura> {
   
   @Override
   public int compare( Temperatura tempA, Temperatura tempB ) {

         // la siguiente linea nos da la diferencia en días entre dos fechas.
       long a = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between( tempA.getFecha(), tempB.getFecha() );
       int salida = 0;

         // debido a que **sort** espera un int...
       if( a > 0 ) {
          salida = 1;
       }
       if( a < 0 ) {
          salida = -1;
       }
       return salida;
    }      
}
```

Luego en tu método **ordenarPorData**, realizas las siguientes modificaciones:

```
private void ordenarPorData() {

     // creas un objeto "comparador"
   TemperaturasPorFecha tempFecha = new TemperaturasPorFecha();

    // le pasas a **sort** la lista a ordenar y el "comparador".
   Collections.sort( temperatures, tempFecha );
}
```

Como habrás deducido, en la clase **Temperatura** debes implementar el "getter", **getFecha()** que te devuelva la fecha...

Observaciones:
"Sobre gustos no hay nada escrito", uno podría trasladar eso al ámbito de los nombres de las clases, métodos y variables, y es verdad que una clase que genere un objeto que tenga como atributos, **nombre**, **apellido**, **documento**, **edad**, **salario**, podría tranquilamente llamarse **Correr**, y el programa funcionaría sin problemas... incluso podríamos llamarla **G**, sin problemas.
Cuando después de un tiempo, te encuentras con la necesidad de modificar algo, te encuentras con una clase **Temperatures**, que...

Jugando a adivinar lo que necesitas que haga tu programa...
El método **afegeix**, recibe como parámetro un objeto **temperatura**, verifica si la lista está vacía, en cuyo caso agrega el objeto recibido a la lista y finaliza su ejecución.
Si la lista no está vacía, verifica que el año del objeto recibido sea el mismo que el del primer objeto guardado, si no es arroja un error (no se como se comporta en ese caso, pero no parece modificar el flujo del programa), si es, guarda en una variable la posición  dentro de la lista del objeto, si es "-1", osea que el objeto no está en la lista, lo agrega a la misma, y acá viene lo raro, si está, lo vuelve a agregar en la misma posición... suponiendo que la posición original era la "3", ahora tendríamos en la posición "3" y en la "4" el mismo objeto... mmmmm.

Comment: Es que mi código está todo traducido en Valenciano y mira que lo estuve pensando en traducirlo. Pero bueno, gracia por la información e intentaré traducirlo en Castellano, porque encima con el profesor que tengo prefiere en Valenciano, que para otros estudiantes se les complica para resolver problemas, porque están acostumbrados en Castellano.

Comment: No me refería al idioma, es tu elección (o la del profe), sino a que el nombre tendría que estar en linea con el contenido, por ejemplo, la clase **Temperatures**, contiene una lista de **Temperatura**, pero no es un objeto **Temperatura** sino una lista, tal vez sería más acorde llamarla **listadoTemperaturas**, o algo así, puede parecer una sutileza, pero créeme que después de seis meses relees el código, y te pasas diez minutos tratando de entender que significado tiene esa clase.